# radio button checked property

Tags: jquery

In my page I have three radio buttons and I want to checked the radio buttons when clicked to the `<li>`. My click function is working but when clicked the radio is not checked.  How can I do that? My code is below

```
$(document).ready(function() {         
     $('#myContainer li').click(function() {
        $('#radio1').attr('checked');            
      });     
});    

<div id="myContainer">
    <li id="li1">
      <input id="radio1" name="RadioGroup" value="val1"  type="radio">
    val1
    </li>  
    <li id="li2">
      <input id="radio2" name="RadioGroup" value="val2"  type="radio">
       val2
    </li>
    <li id="li3">
      <input id="radio3" name="RadioGroup" value="val3" type="radio">
      val3
    </li>
</div>
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You are getting the checked attribute instead of setting it. Try this instead:

```
$('#radio1').attr('checked', 'checked');
```

**Note**

Since jQuery 1.6 it is recommended to use [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) instead of [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).

```
$("#radio1").prop("checked", true);
```

Comment: Worth to mention that in newer jQuery version, it should be `.prop()` instead of `.attr()`

Comment: To be specific, `prop("checked", true)` instead of `attr("checked", "checked")`.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#radio1').attr('checked')'
```

will return you the value, inorder to set the value try

```
$('#myContainer li').click(function() {
        $('#radio1').attr('checked','checked');            
      });
```

or if you are using jquery 1.6+ use [`prop`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

```
$('#myContainer li').click(function() {
            $('#radio1').prop('checked',true);            
          });
```

[**DMEO**](http://jsfiddle.net/rXUZK/)

in your case no matter which `li` you click it will check the radio with id=`#radio1`

---

in my opinion more appropriate behavior would be

```
$('#myContainer li').click(function() {
    $(":input",this).prop('checked',true);            
          });
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/rXUZK/1/)